# OpenCV install error: cvboost.cpp:1439: error: expected ';' before cvReleaseMat

Tags: opencv, installation

Opencv Error:

I got the following error while installing OpenCV on Lucid.

81% ....
"cvboost.cpp:1439: error: expected ';' before cvReleaseMat"

SOLUTION:

edit cvboost.cpp and add semicolon on line:1438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

edit cvboost.cpp and add semicolon on line:1438